# UIView's edge flickers at the end of an animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

My main `UIViewController` has a sub `UIView` named `viewContainer`. It has a couple of `UIImageView`s, `UIButton`s and `UIView`s added to it. In my `viewDidLoad` method I've applied the following to `viewContainer`:

```
self.viewContainer.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.viewContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
self.viewContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
self.viewContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
self.viewContainer.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.viewContainer.layer.bounds].CGPath;

self.viewContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.viewContainer.opaque = YES;
```

When a user presses a button inside the `viewContainer`, I perform the following translation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                         [self.viewContainer setCenter: CGPointApplyAffineTransform(self.viewContainer.center, CGAffineTransformConcat(self.viewContainer.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(60, 0)))];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

My problem is that at the end of the animation, the edge of the view flickers for a fraction of a second (a white vertical line). I've tried setting the frame instead of a transform but still the same result. I'm attempting to do a sort of slide to reveal options thing, which works but flickers on completion.

Any ideas?

Comment: It could be that your are finishing between pixels. Try to set the frame by hand with numbers and see if it still flickers. You could also switch slow animations in simulator to true and hope that you than can see the cause of the problem.

Comment: still the same result, but oddly if I translate in the opposite direction, there's no flicker. Going through all subviews now to see if any exceeds the bounds.

Comment: Did you try to set clipToBounds of the host view?

Comment: Yeah that's set to `YES`